# Was this question really too localized or do people have a vendetta against people who answer their own questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, too-localized

[I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13883388/65387) awhile ago, and then maybe 10 or 15 minutes later I realized what the problem was and so I posted it as an answer, then suddenly people started <del>downvoting (since redacted) the question and</del><sup>[moot]</sup> closing it as "too localized". Was I in the wrong, or do people need to lighten up about answering your own question?

---

It appears I was at fault. Thank you all for clarifying.

Comment: What downvotes are you talking about? I can see none, neither on the Q nor the A. As far as I can see, the question was simply closed because a solution to a very localized problem had been found. Not sure what the problem is? Neither you nor the community did anything wrong here IMO

Comment: What @Pekka said; there are also no down votes on the deleted answer.

Comment: @Pekka: Said person redacted their downvote. How is the solution localized? Because I had reversed the order of the args? I don't think that would be too uncommon of a problem because that's how people think when described a corner, usually. "top left", "bottom right". The solution to my initial problem was found (hence my answer), but the question of whether or not there's a bug in jQuery-UI is still open.

Comment: The person down voted your original version of the question, and removed the down vote once you edited it. I don't see any problem at all there. And yes; a simple switching of arguments seems to be the reason for the close votes.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Alright, I guess that's fair. I should have made it a separate question to determine if there was a bug in jQuery-UI or not (the re-opening issue, which was not part of the original question).

Comment: Ok, now *closed* I've come to terms with, but now deleted...? I mean I don't even care anymore..but...it's not like it was derogatory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For what it's worth, I was one of the close votes. My fault for not leaving a comment. My reasoning was that the order of the arguments in question is (pretty clearly, in my opinion) outlined in the [documentation for position](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) as follows:

> Defines which position on the
>   element being positioned to align with the target element: **"horizontal
>   vertical"** alignment.

The documentation goes on to explain that the ordering of the arguments is based on a CSS convention.

*However*, there *are* lots of questions that could be answered by a simple look at the documentation that aren't closed. I could see it being valuable to people in the future as well. I've voted to reopen.

As a side note, close votes aren't against *you* and aren't meant to be personal (I know it can feel that way sometimes though). They are simply directed at the question. Nobody that closed the question was pursuing a "vendetta." Closing questions is a quality control mechanism for the site, and occasionally there are false positives (which is why the "reopen" functionality exists).

Comment: I think a more proper response is to close those other questions if you run across them. Not reading the documentation is what caused this error. Why exactly do we need questions on Stack Overflow that say the exact same thing as the documentation they *should have* read in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure that just because a question can be answered by digging into the documentation means it should be closed. There's certainly nothing in the FAQ that suggests that (that I saw). Besides, documentation changes, moves, or gets outright removed, which gives *some* value to questions like this.

Comment: I can understand if the docs were ambiguous or vague...

Comment: I guess rethinking it, the question isn't worthy of closing so much as downvotes for poor research. It's basically like asking "I'm confused why this doesn't work because I didn't read the documentation that tells me exactly why it doesn't work." However, I personally see no reason to reopen it now that it's closed.

Comment: This I can accept. Thank you. I admit not having researched thoroughly enough. I thought it was because I self-answered because of Frédéric's comment.

Comment: Hi @animuson, in a perfect world, we'd all be able to download Google into our skulls and all the world's problems would be solved. Since there's so much information out there, including lots and lots and *lots* of documentation, Stack Overflow can sometimes help make it easier to find the information that's buried in mounds of documentation. I'm sure you can think of a time where you just got "reader's block" where you've stared at documentation and still missed what you were looking for, yet found it on some historical forum post. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Consensus seems to be that the problem and solution was too trivial (simple misordering of arguments) to warrant a question.

Follow-up bugs should be submitted as new questions.

Comment: Users often close typo and questions from such as too localised because they are

Comment: @random: That's fine, I understand that, but this was more of an understanding issue; not a typo. I thought I was doing everything right, I didn't get any syntax errors, but the output was just a little off.